# SQL UNION 2 SELECT on same table

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have 2 SELECT on the same table "contratto"; in php (and mysql) I do it as:

```
$sql_1=" SELECT * FROM contratto WHERE  id_cliente='2'   " ;
$sql_2=" SELECT * FROM contratto  JOIN cliente ON  contratto.id_cliente=cliente.id WHERE cliente.id_rivenditore = '2'  " ;
$sql= "(" . $sql_1 . ") UNION ALL (" . $sql_2 .")  ; ";
mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($risultato_query)) { ..... }
```

The 2 SQL query $sql_1 and $sql_2 separately work fine.
The query $sql (union of $sql_1 and $sql_2) doesn't work, that is:

```
( SELECT * FROM contratto WHERE id_cliente=’2′ ) UNION ALL ( SELECT * FROM contratto JOIN cliente ON contratto.id_cliente=cliente.id WHERE cliente.id_rivenditore = ‘2’ ) ;
```

I get the error "mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in ..."

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

At least one error is coming from the `union`.  All subqueries in the union need to have the same columns, so `select *` is not appropriate (especially in this case).

Another error comes from PHP, because you are not checking for errors from SQL.  If you did, you would see the error message from the database.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the solution then? I need to get all the columns as result. Can you suggest a Sql string? May be without union and using another way

Comment: I tried replacing * with id but I get the same error

Comment: @Fausto70 . . . This explains why your query doesn't work -- which seems to be the question you are asking.  If you want to know how to do something, then ask *another* question and provide sample data and desired results.